# Wpf  app with bgImage

Tags: wpf

I'm very new to this WPF technology, I started with a sticky note application which should  looks similar to IPhone's Note taking applicaiton or like the sticky note addin for visual studio [Please see this-Visual studio Addin](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/StickyNotes)

Can anyone please guide me  how to achieve this task , or atleast the textbox background with lines inserted.[Visual studio Addin](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/StickyNotes)

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border Background="#FF855E36" BorderBrush="#FF855E36"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BorderThickness="10" Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <TextBlock 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            FontFamily="Comic Sans MS"
            FontStyle="Normal" 
            Foreground="White"
            >Sticky</TextBlock>
    </Border>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2"  Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <TextBox x:Name="txtWritePad" Background="Yellow" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" AcceptsReturn="True"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It  is just a background image that is set to the tile mode:

```
<TextBox>

  <TextBox.Background>

    <ImageBrush ImageSource="bg.png" Viewport="0,0,7,18" ViewportUnits="Absolute" TileMode="Tile"/>

  </TextBox.Background>

</TextBox>
```

Credit goes to :[Jarrey](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Profile/en-US/?user=Jarrey&referrer=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/f68f5113-9119-48b4-8d9a-fd3090121e7d/&rh=Xp20QaFRsmUYKi9vYH7SsU/3vsb96pebgf3akVN%2bXms%3d&sp=forums)